# Optional Cancellation points

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, posix

I just want to know the meaning of optional Cancellation point. Like we have mandatory cancellation point which means cancellation point shall occur when any of the functions that comes under mandatory cancellation points is called in a thread. So, is it like for optional one , cancellation point may occur or may not. I have check SO for this but i didn't find any exact answer regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX *requires* certain functions to be a cancellation point and says cancellation points  *may* occur in certain functions (optional cancellation points). You can read the entire list of mandatory and optional cancellation points from the manual [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html):

```
 Cancellation points
       POSIX.1 specifies that certain functions must, and certain other
       functions may, be cancellation points.  If a thread is cancelable,
       its cancelability type is deferred, and a cancellation request is
       pending for the thread, then the thread is canceled when it calls a
       function that is a cancellation point.
```